# How to use DSP toolbox of Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, toolbox

I would like to know how should I use the `dsp.AudioPlayer` and `dsp.AudioRecorder` in a Matlab program. I have a wav file called y.wav, and I want to play this file through my sound card and record it back in my PC.

How do I go on with this?

Comment: maybe by checking the documents!!?

Comment: MATLAB has the best manual ever, but people still prefer not to use it cause they are lazy...